# How to input and return values from a method with generic types?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create the method **deNull()** to check input values. These input value might be String, int, double, Timestamp. Therefore, I create the method with generics types.

If the input value is null, then it will return "";

If the input value is not null, then return the original value.

My code is as below:

```
public static <T> T deNull(T value){
    if(value == null ){
        return "";
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

However, this method freaks out at line 3 and shows **Type mismatch: Cannot convert from String to T.**

How should I amend this method to make it run as expected ?

Comment: What should be returned in the none `String` cases? `""` is not a valid `Integer`.

Comment: If a non String  value input and it is not null, just return the original value. For example, if input number 88, then just return 88.

Comment: That wasn't the question k5_ asked. If `T` is `Integer` and `value` is `null`, what should return value be? It cannot be `""`, that's for sure, and that is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: If T is Integer and value is null, then I also want it to return String "". Is it able to do so ?

Comment: No, because if `T` is `Integer`, then method is `public static Integer deNull(Integer value)`, and you cannot return a `String` when the return type is `Integer`.

Comment: You seem to be asking for code that sets an `int`, `double` or `Timestamp` to `""`.  Understandably, your compiler thinks this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` and `double` can not be `null` anyway, that leaves `Timestamp` and `String` as the only two options.

In my opinion just write both methods without generics, not worth the hassle.

If you actually need it for more than two types, i would suggest changing the method to.

```
public static <T> T deNull(T value, T orElse){
    if(value == null ){
        return orElse;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}   

String x = deNull( string, "");
Integer y = deNull( integer, 0);
```

(I would also suggest to change the method name to `valueOrElse`)

Comment: `T` cannot be `int` or `double`, so that part of answer is irrelevant.

Comment: These types came from original question.

Comment: Even if question is wrong, doesn't mean your answer should be. Generic type parameters cannot be primitives. They can be the boxed equivalent, though.

Comment: Not sure where my answer is wrong. primitives can not be null, so the method doesnt make sense for them(with autoboxing you can use it but it will never enter the `== null` branch). My suggested alternative method works for primitives and object-types.

Comment: Thank you both for clarifying. =D Your suggestion is helpful for my project.

Answer (score 2):

Since the return value is always a String type, decouple it from parameter type T.

```
public static <T> String deNull(T value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This might also be a great approach if we only want to return String value. = )

Answer (score 0):

If the 'T' is String your line 3 is valid else it is fail.

```
return "";
```

If the T is Integer  string cannot cast to Integer

```
Integer a = 5;
String s = (String)a;//You cannot do like this
```

Comment: `T` cannot be `int`.